# How can I read a textfile into matlab and make it a list?

Tags: matlab, file-io, import, text-files

I have a textfile that has the format

```
 gene            complement(22995..24539)
                 /gene="ppp"
                 /locus_tag="MRA_0020"
 CDS             complement(22995..24539)
                 /gene="ppp"
                 /locus_tag="MRA_0020"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="putative serine/threonine phosphatase Ppp"
                 /protein_id="ABQ71738.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:148503929"
 gene            complement(24628..25095)
                 /locus_tag="MRA_0021"
 CDS             complement(24628..25095)
                 /locus_tag="MRA_0021"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="hypothetical protein"
                 /protein_id="ABQ71739.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:148503930"
 gene            complement(25219..26802)
                 /locus_tag="MRA_0022"
 CDS             complement(25219..26802)
                 /locus_tag="MRA_0022"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="hypothetical protein"
                 /protein_id="ABQ71740.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:148503931"
```

I would like to read the textfile into Matlab and make a list with the information from the line gene as the starting point for each item in the list. So for this example there will be 3 items in the list. I have tried a few things and cannot get this to work. Anyone have any ideas of what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick suggestion for an algorithm:

1. Open the file with `fopen`
2. Start reading lines with `fgetl` until you find a line that starts with `'CDS'`.
3. Keeep reading lines until you get another line that starts with `'gene'`.
4. For all the lines between the line in (2) and in (3)

   - find the string between `'/'` and `'='`. This is the fieldname
   - find the string between the quotes. This is the value of the field
5. Up the counter by one, and start from #2 till you're done reading the file

These commands may be helpful:

- To find a string enclosed by specific
  characters, use e.g.
  `regexp(lineThatHasBeenRead,'/(.+)=','tokens','once')`
- To create
  the output structure, use dynamic
  field names, e.g.
  `output(ct).(fieldname) = value;`

---

**EDIT**

Here's some code. I saved your example as 'test.txt'.

```
% open file
fid = fopen('test.txt');

% parse the file
eof = false;
geneCt = 1;
clear output % you cannot reassign output if it exists with different fieldnames already
output(1:1000) = struct; % you may want to initialize fields here
while ~eof
    % read lines till we find one with CDS
    foundCDS = false;
    while ~foundCDS
        currentLine = fgetl(fid);
        % check for eof, then CDS. Allow whitespace at the beginning
        if currentLine == -1
            % end of file
            eof = true;
        elseif ~isempty(regexp(currentLine,'^\s+CDS','match','once'))
            foundCDS = true;
        end
    end % looking for CDS

    if ~eof

        % read (and remember) lines till we find 'gene'
        collectedLines = cell(1,20); % assume no more than 20 lines pere gene. Row vector for looping below
        foundGene = false;
        lineCt = 1;
        while ~foundGene
            currentLine = fgetl(fid);
            % check for eof, then gene. Allow whitespace at the beginning
            if currentLine == -1;
                % end of file - consider all data has been read
                eof = true;
                foundGene = true;
            elseif ~isempty(regexp(currentLine,'^\s+gene','match','once'))
                foundGene = true;
            else
                collectedLines{lineCt} = currentLine;
                lineCt = lineCt + 1;
            end
        end

        % loop through collectedLines and assign. Do not loop through the
        % gene line
        for line = collectedLines(1:lineCt-1)
            fieldname = regexp(line{1},'/(.+)=','tokens','once');
            value = regexp(line{1},'="?([^"]+)"?$','tokens','once');
            % try converting value to number
            numValue = str2double(value);
            if isfinite(numValue)
                value = numValue;
            else
                value = value{1};
            end
            output(geneCt).(fieldname{1}) = value;
        end
        geneCt = geneCt + 1;
    end
end % while eof

% cleanup
fclose(fid);
output(geneCt:end) = [];
```